# Enemies don't target the spawned Player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a team game (dungeon crawler) and I was faced with a problem.
If we put the player prefab directly in the sceane the enemies treat the player correctly (follow, attack, etc). The problem is: my peer created a player spawn pad that instantiate the exacly same prefab but the enemies ignore completly the player.
Can someone help me?

Here's the enemy script:

```
    public bool isDead = false;
    public float speed = 4f;
    public int hp = 0;
    public int dmg = 0;
    public int def = 0;
    public int amtSouls = 0;

    //Item drop
    public GameObject drop;
 

    //follow player
    public GameObject Player;
    private NavMeshAgent Enemy;
    public float enemyDistanceRun = 5.0f; //radius to spot the player

    //--
    Rigidbody rb;
    Scene currentScene;
    PlayerHealthScript phs;
    
    

    public Type type; //defines the type (common, elite, boss)

    public enum Type
    {
        Common,
        Elite,
        Boss
    }

   

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //not working
            hp -= phs.dmg;
        }


    }


    void death()
    {
        isDead = true;
        Instantiate(drop, transform.position, drop.transform.rotation);

        //---- get Destroy script reference
        GameObject ds = GameObject.Find("Soul");
        Destroy des = ds.GetComponent<Destroy>();
        //----

        Destroy(gameObject);
        //send the amount of souls to the Destroy script
        des.sls += amtSouls;

      


    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Enemy = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        phs = GameObject.Find("Player Character").GetComponent<PlayerHealthScript>();
        currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
       
        //  gate.SetActive(false);


        if (CompareTag(Type.Common.ToString()))
        {
            hp = 60;
            dmg = 5;
            def = 5;
            amtSouls = 10;
            // gate.SetActive(true);
        } 
        else
        if(CompareTag(Type.Elite.ToString()))
        {
            hp = 100;
            dmg = 15;
            def = 10;
            amtSouls = 25;
        }
        else
        if(CompareTag(Type.Boss.ToString()))
        {
            hp = 200;
            dmg = 25;
            def = 20;
            amtSouls = 50;
        }


     

        // Retrieve the index of the scene in the project's build settings.
        int buildIndex = currentScene.buildIndex;

        // Check the scene and multiply the values
        switch (buildIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                //Do nothing because values already setted
                break;
            case 1:
                hp = hp * 2;
                dmg = dmg * 2;
                def = def * 2;
                amtSouls = amtSouls + 2;
                
                break;
        }




    }



    void Update()
    {


        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.transform.position);

        //chase player
        if(distance < enemyDistanceRun)
        {
            Vector3 dirToPlayer = transform.position - Player.transform.position;
            Vector3 newPos = transform.position - dirToPlayer;

            Enemy.SetDestination(newPos);
        }





        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            death();
        }
```

Player Spawn Pad Script:

```
public GameObject PlayerPrefab;
    public GameObject MainCam;
    public GameObject FreelookCam;
    public GameObject PlayerHUD;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject Player = Instantiate(PlayerPrefab, transform.localPosition, transform.localRotation);
        Player.name = PlayerPrefab.name;

        GameObject MainCam1 = Instantiate(MainCam, transform.localPosition, transform.localRotation);
        MainCam1.name = MainCam.name;

        GameObject FreeCam = Instantiate(FreelookCam, transform.localPosition, transform.localRotation);
        FreeCam.name = FreelookCam.name;

        GameObject HUD = Instantiate(PlayerHUD, transform.localPosition, transform.localRotation);
        HUD.name = PlayerHUD.name;

        GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: Seems like enemy never checks if there is some new Player to be chased, but target is assigned on creating the enemy. Enemy needs to check for players on update loop also.

Comment: and can you tell me what's the best solution for that? @Saplu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution.

```
        {
            Vector3 dirToPlayer = transform.position - Player.transform.position;///<-
            Vector3 newPos = transform.position - dirToPlayer;

            Enemy.SetDestination(newPos);
        }
```

```
  if (distance < enemyDistanceRun)
            {
                Vector3 dirToPlayer = transform.position - phs.transform.position;//<-
                Vector3 newPos = transform.position - dirToPlayer;

                Enemy.SetDestination(newPos);
                Debug.Log("Chacing.");
            }
```

The enemy was following the Player gameobject that, for some reason didn't recognize so I put it to follow the player health script holder and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in a comment, your enemy never checks if a new Player is spawned.
*"The best solution"* depends on how often you are going to spawn and destroy that player GameObject.
For example, if you're only going to spawn the player at the beginning of the scene, then you could alter the scripts' execution order so that the player is spawned before the enemy tries to look for it.

```
[DefaultExecutionOrder(-50)]
class PlayerSpawnPad : MonoBehaviour { /* ... */ }
```

And in the enemy class you get the reference in one of these three ways:

```
player = GameObject.Find("Player Character");
// Not really recommended. If you decide to change the game object's name
// later in the project, you'd have to change this too.

player = FindObjectWithTag("Player");
// Better, but although tags are less likely to be changed, it's still
// something more to think about

player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
// If you ever decide to change the player script's name, the compiler will
// tell you immediately
```

If instead you plan on spawning the player after the enemy, you could use an event

```
using System;

class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public static event Action<Player> onPlayerSpawned;

    private void Start() {
        onPlayerSpawned(this);
    }

    /* ... */
}

class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    private GameObject player;

    private void Start() {
        Player.onPlayerSpawned += RegisterPlayer;
    }

    private void RegisterPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player.gameObject;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```